# Using CSS or JavaScript to identify a set word or phrase and format only it differently (eg.colour, size)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, formatting

First proper question to my fellow coders, so here goes;

I have had an obscure request from a client to make it so in his "Knack" reporting software every time the word "1st Job" appears within the generated tables it is formatted Bold & Coloured Red.

### eg.

|  4th Job  |  7th Job  |  2nd Job  |  **1st Job**  | 9th Job |

I was thinking along the lines in my psuedocode:

```
if text displayed ("1st Job") {
format text:
font-weight: bold;
font-color: Red;
}
```

The only options presented to perform said formatting are JavaScript & CSS

I am still learning the intricacies of CSS and JavaScript is dribbling into my brain daily but have yet to come across this request anywhere as yet.

Please if anyone is aware of a possible solution do share and I will be greatly appreciative.

Many Thanks in advance,
Al

Comment: Additional note: I also cannot code in a <span> tag to the text as its imported from a database and then within the reporting software needs to come out with the set formatting of strong, red text.

Comment: java != javascript (I fixed the tags)

Comment: Another note: Jquery is installed also if anyone has a workaround using that script.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div, p').each(function() {
  var job = $(this).text().replace(/1st Job /g, "<font>1st Job </font>");
  $(this).html(job);
});
```

```css
font {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>1st Job Ipsum rule britannia lorem fish and chips ipsum going to the loo cheers mate crumpets mate off to the pub good day 1st Job harry potter cup of tea cup of tea crumpets God save the queen jolly good show rule britannia cheerio! bangers and mash</p>
</section>
```

Comment: This one also broke the app by only displaying an unformatted header

Comment: Got the app working, but there is no change to the formatting. Is this due to the '$(this).html(job);'   Will this work on other pagetypes eg. php etc.

Comment: This is jquery. I am not familiar with how php works.

Comment: do you suspect any reason as to why this does not work at present? no errors are presented within the console, the table contents have not been effected however.

Comment: Are you using my code directly or for your table rows did you change $('div,p') to $('tr'). Cannot tell the problem exactly without looking at the code.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I require it to cover all table rows also not just one in particular, try not to think of this issue as table content specific, but simply if the "1st Job" text is in the page it needs to be re-formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized i solved this earlier with pure javascript

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {    
         if (col.innerText == "1st Job") { // You might want to look at other solutions in case the TD shouldnt be case sensitive and so on
             col.style.backgroundColor = "#f00"; //or the actuall styling you want
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code appears to have broken the app :-/ love the code though, simple and clean for non-capitalised purposes. Thoughts on why it may have removed the table completely.. the web app in use is Knack

Comment: huh, that's very strange. The only place in my code that the dom is manipulated is at the "col.style.backgroundcolor" part. Could you see if the table still deletes itself if you remove this part?  Are you sure the table is still getting created at the start at all?

Comment: commented out the line, header refreshed with no table, which is the same outcome as before

Comment: console.log(table) after the line "var table = ...". Any other information would help. Try testing the loop in a try/catch?

Comment: this is the console error I'm encountering:- TypeError: table is undefined from the first code.    And this was the error encountered from the console.log(table) :- TypeError: table is undefined

Comment: wait, you did change the very first line "var table = document.getElementById("table1");" to select your table's ID, right?

Comment: certainly did ("view_237") is the table id

Comment: Could it be that you are creating the table asynchronously and therefore, my loop runs before the table exists?  I don't know Knack, but maybe there's a success-condition for the table creation that you can put the loop it?

Comment: Within knack, custom Javascript will be called after the Knack app has been loaded.